# How can i calculate bigmod(bigmod(a^n)-bigmod(b^m))?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, number-theory

I want calculate

> (a^n % k - b^m %k)%k

But **a^n** and **b^m** can be very large

> Bigmod(bigmod(a^n)-bigmod(b^m)) ?

I have tried to calculate **bigmod(a^n) - bigmod(b^m)** and then used **bigmod** for the subtraction result then I realized it gave a wrong answer!
 is there any to calculate this ?

```
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

template<class T>T big_mod(T n,T p,T m)
   {
     if(p==0)
       return (T)1;
      T x=big_mod(n,p/2,m);
         x=(x*x)%m;
         if(p&1)
          x=(x*n)%m;
           return x;
    }

int main()
{
   long long int a=37,b=26,m=10,n=20,mod=1000000008,x,y,z;
    x=big_mod(a,m,mod);
    y=big_mod(b,n,mod);
    z=((x%mod-y%mod)%mod);
     cout<<z;
}
```

Comment: Would interest me, too. Is it this: https://golammostaeen.wordpress.com/2012/10/20/big-mod-algorithm/ ?

Comment: @Nidhoegger Yes right !

Comment: Show some code pls and add a Tag of the programming language. We wont do the work for you, but we will help finding your errors...

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you mean by `bigmod` in this context.

Comment: I'm guessing that your modulo operator returns negative numbers when you weren't expecting it.

Comment: Yes that is what happened @DavidEisenstat

Comment: I added my code . @Nidhoegger

Comment: @CodeHead Please provide proper and readable formatting!

Comment: Within `bigmod()` you must also take the modulus at each step of the power calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How can i calculate bigmod(bigmod(a^n)-bigmod(b^m)) ?
```

Let your modulus be `k`. Your expression is equivalent to:

```
((a^n) % k - (b^m) % k + k) % k
```

You need to add `k` because the subtraction can lead to a negative result. This will make it positive, without affecting the result, since `k % k == 0`.

To compute `(x^y) % k`, use the exponentiation by squaring algorithm and make sure you take the modulo at each step:

```
x^y % k = ((x^(y / 2))^2) % k if y is even
          (x*x^(y - 1)) % k   else
```

For your code, assuming everything else works, you just need to change this line:

```
z=((x%mod-y%mod)%mod);
```

to this:

```
z=((x%mod-y%mod+mod)%mod);
```

Comment: but i have to calculate the modulus of both a^n and b^n .

Comment: @CodeHead yes, I wrote how to do that. For more details, you were also given this link: https://golammostaeen.wordpress.com/2012/10/20/big-mod-algorithm/

Comment: @CodeHead I added what you should change your code to. Please see if that does it.